# Zend\Session invalid setting

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-session

I'm working with Zend Framework 3 and after configuring the session in my module.config.php, I receive this fatal error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\Session\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: 'session.class' is not a valid sessions-related ini setting`

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is what I have in module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Session\Config\ConfigInterface' => 'Zend\Session\Service\SessionConfigFactory',
    ),
),
'session_config' => array(
    'phpSaveHandler' => 'files',
    'savePath' => 'C:/xampp/tmp',
    'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\StandardConfig',


'session_storage' => array(
    'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
),
'session_validators' => array(
    'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
    'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove following from session_config

```
'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\StandardConfig',
```